# import settings to resharper 7 from 6.3

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, resharper-6.1, resharper-7.0

I have been a resharper user for a number of years and a member of team that use the product. As a team we have created a common resharper xml settings file that we import in to resharper so that we are all working off the same settings.

I recently updated to resharper 7 but cant find where I can import the resharper settings file. Its probably really obvious but I need some assistance with such?

Answer (score 1):

Under the ReSharper top-level menu, click on "Manage Options...". You'll see a dropdown menu called Import/Export settings.

Comment: As explained in the ReSharper 7(.1.3) interface itself, do not get sidetracked by Options > Code Editing > Code Style Sharing to import settings unless your settings file comes from < ReSharper 6.1.  Yes, a settings file from ReSharper 6.3 (being >= 6.1) should be imported through Manage Options... instead, and the above answer should likely be marked accepted. ;)